# How to correctly write information into GlassFish log?

Tags: java, logging, glassfish

I have built a simple Java servlet on my Eclipse Kepler IDE, GlassFish 4.0 server. In order to track the output, I used both `System.out.println()` and `log.info()` method from `java.util.logging`, but no information is found in the GlassFish log file.

Comment: Is the servlet working? Is anything coming into the log file at all?

Comment: @GudmundurOrn it is working, now it is logging into the console for some reason, without my changing anything.